# How to handle System.FormatException if we don't know the data type

Tags: c#

In a calculator application, I have to convert the string the user inputs to a data type, but I don't know if it is a float, integer, double, etc, and I wrote:

```
value += double.Parse(result.Text);
```

Whenever I write something like 12.25, it appears System.FormatException. However, if I write 2 or 89, the program runs without any problem.

I really don't know what to do, I've tried changing the double to float but the same error appears.

Comment: `double.TryParse(string, out double)`...

Comment: Try use `TryParse` and do not forget using `CultureInfo` and `NumberStyles`.

Comment: It seems you already know the data type. For a calculator I would always expect double. I would try setting explicitly the culture, probably your computer is in some culture that has a decimal comma.

Comment: It probably because your `․` is not `.`.

Comment: By default, `double.Parse()` method gets number decimal separator sign from `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` property, unless you will pass `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` parameter to `Parse()` method (in that situation it will set separator sign to `CurrencyDecimalSeparator` property).

Comment: `value += double.TryParse(result.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var item) 
        ? item 
        : 0.0;`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `InvariantCulture` for user input. As a user I expect you to respect my language settings, e.g.. dot as a group separator and comma as decimal separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safer way is to use `TryParse`

```
double.TryParse(string, out double)
```

Also keep in mind that parsing is culture related. To make sure your decimal separator is `.`, not `,` you could do something like this:

```
double.Parse(result.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone! The problem disappeared when I added CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in the Parse method as scor4er said. I also added "using System.Globalization;" at the beginning, thank you.

Comment: I would advice *against* `TryParse`. Here the input is totally controlled by the program and will never be invalid, except for bugs. It'll only hide problems instead of preventing them.

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't think we know enough to say that. It's user input, and we don't know whether this is an application where it's reasonable to ensure that `result.Text` will be valid before anything tries to parse it.

Comment: @Alejandro the calculators could be different, you could enter expressions as text in some of them :) For op's case I agree, the `TryParse` could hide the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

`TryParse` is a good way, but is there a particular reason to not use `Convert`?

```
value += Convert.ToDouble(result.Text);
```

Of course, you could get into trouble if you're in places like Europe, where comma is used in place of a decimal point, in which case you need to allow for culture.